# Form Validation Radio Button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate my form in HTML using JavaScript, specifically to check whether user click either one of the radio button. Part of my code is as below:

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Your unit</legend>
                <label for="COS10011"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS10011">COS10011</label>
                <label for="COS60004"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS60004">COS60004</label>
                <label for="COS60007"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS60007">COS60007</label><BR>
                <p><label>Your Tutor: </label>
                    <select name="tutor" id="tutor">
                        <option value="tutor1" selected="selected">Tutor 1</option>
                        <option value="tutor2">Tutor 2</option>
                        <option value="tutor3">Tutor 3</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
        </fieldset>
```

JavaScript:

```
function isUnitSelected(){
    var selected = false;
    var isCOS10011 = document.getElementById("COS10011").checked;
    var isCOS60004 = document.getElementById("COS60004").checked;
    var isCOS60007 = document.getElementById("COS60007").checked;
    
    if (isCOS10011 || isCOS60004 || isCOS60007)
        selected = true; //we haven't used {}. BE CAREFUL about adding extra lines
    else{
        selected = false;
        gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Select a sex for your cat\n"
    }
    
    return selected;
}
```

Comment: You can initially check one of the radio buttons by default. So you won't have to check whether the any of them is selected

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? How is your code used, how does it fail? Here's how to validate in the submission event: https://jsfiddle.net/rm9s0pv4/

Comment: @firatozcevahir ah i see, may I know how to do that?

Comment: Simply add `checked` attribute to one of the radio buttons. Like this: `<input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS10011" checked>`

Comment: @ChrisG the JavaScript that is shown could not validate whether either one of the button is selected, like it does not do anything to the form

Comment: @firatozcevahir ah i see, but the requirement is to not have any one of it checked and to be left empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute to one of your radio buttons in the group, it'll trigger native validation:

```html
<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your unit</legend>
    <label for="COS10011"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS10011" required>COS10011</label>
    <label for="COS60004"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS60004">COS60004</label>
    <label for="COS60007"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS60007">COS60007</label>
    <br/>
    <p>
      <label>Your Tutor: </label>
      <select name="tutor" id="tutor">
        <option value="tutor1" selected="selected">Tutor 1</option>
        <option value="tutor2">Tutor 2</option>
        <option value="tutor3">Tutor 3</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

---

JS version:

```js
function isUnitSelected() {
  const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="unit"]');
  const selected = [...radios].some(radio => radio.checked);
  if (!selected) {
    let gErrorMsg = "Select a sex for your cat\n";
    console.log(gErrorMsg);
  }
  return selected;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return isUnitSelected()">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your unit</legend>
    <label for="COS10011"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS10011">COS10011</label>
    <label for="COS60004"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS60004">COS60004</label>
    <label for="COS60007"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS60007">COS60007</label>
    <br/>
    <p>
      <label>Your Tutor: </label>
      <select name="tutor" id="tutor">
        <option value="tutor1" selected="selected">Tutor 1</option>
        <option value="tutor2">Tutor 2</option>
        <option value="tutor3">Tutor 3</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: will it make all the radio button must be selected?

Comment: @cpw yes you can see in the above demo if any radio is selected from the group then the form submits

Comment: that would be the default web validation right? but i need a different validation, the one that shows the pop out box if any part of the form is not filled in

Comment: @cpw native validation has JavaScript hooks as well, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation

Comment: @cpw check the second snippet with custsom JS validation

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `document.getElementsByName` to do so.

```js
function checkIt(){
     let unit=document.getElementsByName("unit");
   let selected = false;
   for (let i=0;i<unit.length;i++){
        if (unit[i].checked){
        selected = true;
        break;
      }
   }
   if (!selected){
    gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Select a sex for your cat\n";
    alert(gErrorMsg);
   }
   return selected;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Your unit</legend>
    <label for="COS10011"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS10011" >COS10011</label>
    <label for="COS60004"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS60004">COS60004</label>
    <label for="COS60007"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS60007">COS60007</label>
    <br/>
    <p>
      <label>Your Tutor: </label>
      <select name="tutor" id="tutor">
        <option value="tutor1" selected="selected">Tutor 1</option>
        <option value="tutor2">Tutor 2</option>
        <option value="tutor3">Tutor 3</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <button onclick="checkIt()">Go</button>
```

Comment: ah i see, but is there a way to put the whole thing into the js file as it is in a separate file instead of this <button onclick="checkIt()">Go</button>

Comment: I modified the `checkIt` function to fulfil your need, you just copy the content of it to your `isUnitSelected' function, it should be work.

Comment: and it's supposed to show a pop out message if non of the radio are chosen

Comment: Have you check the return value?

Comment: I have updated the script, it should fulfil your need.

Answer (score 0):

Work Awesome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<fieldset>
            <legend>Your unit</legend>
                <label for="COS10011"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS10011" class="radio" value="1">COS10011</label>
                <label for="COS60004"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS60004" class="radio" value="2">COS60004</label>
                <label for="COS60007"><input type="radio" name="unit" id="COS60007" class="radio"  value="3">COS60007</label><BR>
                <p><label>Your Tutor: </label>
                    <select name="tutor" id="tutor">
                        <option value="1" selected="selected">Tutor 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Tutor 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Tutor 3</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
        </fieldset>
</body>
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.radio').click(function () {
           selectElement('tutor', $(this).val());
       });
   });
   

  function selectElement(id, valueToSelect) {    
      let element = document.getElementById(id);
      element.value = valueToSelect;
    }

    
</script>
</html>
```